# returning inner-class object from interface

Tags: java, class, interface, inner-classes, enumeration

```
/**
* Created by unibodydesignn on 11.03.2017. 
*/
public interface Enumeration
{
// Returns true if another element in the collection exists
public boolean hasNext();
// Returns the next element in the collection as an Object
public Object getNext(); }


/**
 * NameCollection implements a collection of names using
 * a simple array.

 */
public class NameCollection
{
String[] names;
//this array will be initiliazed at outside

NameCollection(String[] names)
{
    this.names = names;
}
/**
 * getEnumeration should return an instance of a class that
 implements
 * the Enumeration interface where hasNext() and getNext()
 * correspond to data stored within the names array.
 */
Enumeration getEnumeration ()
{

}

public boolean hasNext()
{
  //i will define this method here
}

public Object getNext()
{
 //i will define getNext() here
}
```

Complete the method getEnumeration() so that it returns an   anonymous     inner class that corresponds to the Enumeration interface for the names array in
NamesCollection. Then write a main method that creates a NamesCollection
object with a sample array of strings, retrieves the Enumeration for this class via
getEnumeration(), and then iterates through the enumeration outputting each
name using the getNext() method.

I don't understand this question's concept. I clearly do not know what to do or where to start? Can I find Java's default hasNext() definition?
It is not homework.
It is a programming project from Absolute Java book. Chapter 13. P3.

Comment: I doubt that this book makes such a question out of thin air. Did you read and understand the preceding chapter(s)? And what do you mean with “Java's default hasNext() definition”? Why should Java have a default definition for your custom interface?

Answer (score 1):

> Complete the method `getEnumeration()` so that it returns an anonymous inner class that corresponds to the `Enumeration` interface for the names array in `NamesCollection`.

The purpose of the exercise seems to be working with anonymous classes.
For example, instead of creating a *named* class like this:

```
class NamesEnumeration implements Enumeration {
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public Object getNext() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

... the instructions guide you to use an *anonymous* class instead, like this:

```
    Enumeration getEnumeration() {
        return new Enumeration() {
            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public Object getNext() {
                // ...
            }
        };
    }
```

An important point is that anonymous implementation can use variables visible in its scope. Most notably for this example,
the `names` field of the enclosing `NamesCollection` class.

In the `NamesCollection` class,
you don't need the `hasNext` and `getNext` methods.
So the class should look something like this:

```
public class NameCollection {
    final String[] names;

    NameCollection(String[] names) {
        this.names = names.clone();
    }

    Enumeration getEnumeration() {
        return new Enumeration() {
            int currentIndex = 0;
            //  ^^^^^^^^^^^^ this is a hint for you

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                // ...
            }

            @Override
            public Object getNext() {
                // ...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

I've made some minor improvements, and added a hint to help you complete the implementation.

Lastly, the exercise also asks to add a `main` method to exercise this class. That should be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] sample = {"hello", "world"};
    NameCollection namesCollection = new NameCollection(sample);
    Enumeration names = namesCollection.getEnumeration();
    while (names.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(names.getNext());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i dont know about that book you say, but lets understand what is requested:

What you need to do is create an implementation of the `Enumeration Interface`, i dont know if this chapter is about `Interfaces`, or `Enumarations`.

**1:** *"Complete the method getEnumeration() so that it returns an anonymous inner class that corresponds to the Enumeration interface for the names array in NamesCollection"*.

Here you need to return an implementation of the `Enumeration` interface, the question says to create an Anonymous class (but i sugest to create an Inner Class, maybe Private Inner Class). like this, inside the `NameCollection` class:

```
public Enumeration getEnumeration(){
  Enumeration enumerat = new Enumeration(){
    private int index = 0;

    public boolean hasNext(){
      return names.length > index;
    }
    public Object getNext(){
      return names[index++];
    }
  };
  return enumerat;
}
```

The method returns an implementation of the `Enumeration` class that you can use to traverse throught the array of names you passed to the constructor of the `NameCollection` class.

**2:** *"Then write a main method that creates a NamesCollection object with a sample array of strings, retrieves the Enumeration for this class via getEnumeration(), and then iterates through the enumeration outputting each name using the getNext() method"*.

Here you just need to create a test class for your implementation:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    NameCollection nc = new NameCollection(new String[]{ "Adriane", "Beatriz" });
    Enumeration en = nc.getEnumeration();
    while( en.hasNext() ){
      System.out.printf("Name: %s \n", en.getNext() );
    }

  }

}
```